# how to remove elements in document fragment after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, documentfragment

I'm working on a javascript project in which I use a document fragment to append several span elements at once. Then they are animated with css.

```
.redCircle {
    float: left;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px red;
    background-color: red;
    animation: 2s circleFall linear;
}

@keyframes circleFall {
    0%{margin:0;}
    100%{margin:100% 10%;}
}


setInterval(thingyTime, 5000);

function thingyTime() {
    var count = 15,
        spanVar = document.createElement("span"),
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) { 

        for (var j = 0; j < 1; ++j) { 
            spanVar = document.createElement('spanVar');
            spanVar.className = "redCircle";
            fragment.appendChild(spanVar);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(fragment);

};

thingyTime();
```

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the spans after the animation is completed. I have used

```
setTimeout(function(){

    spanVar.remove(spanVar.selectedIndex);

},2000); // <= animation length
```

and it works fine when it's only for one element, but I need to remove *all* the elements in the fragment.

I aprreciate your help.

Comment: After the loop `spanVar` will just be a reference to the last span you created (since the for loop overwrites it each time). You are also creating elements of type `spanVar` not actual spans (unsure if thats intentional). Easiest solution, stick all the elements you create in an array, then just iterate that to tidy em up.

Comment: Yes, @Carl I noticed that it was creating elements with the variable name and I thought it was wierd. I haven't been able to find anything about it after googling. Could you maybe explain it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few bits (further to my initial comment). For generating, I'd drop the extra `createElement("span")` at the top, since it never gets used. Then create span's in the loop, rather than `spanVar`'s (assuming the are unwanted). For the create element method you just give it the element type you want it to make.

```
function thingyTime() {
    var count = 15,
        spanVar,
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < 1; ++j) { 
            spanVar = document.createElement('span');
            spanVar.className = "redCircle";
            fragment.appendChild(spanVar);
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(fragment);
};
```

For cleanup, easiest way is just use the class you created. Query for em all, & then nuke em one by one.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".redCircle").forEach(function(c){
    c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
});
```

If you have other instances of the redCircle you don't want to nuke on the other hand. I'd add a `var circlesToCleanup = [];` then in the creation loop push each of em on to it `circlesToCleanup.push(spanVar)`

Then when you call your cleanup, iterate `circlesToCleanup` rather than the querySelector output.

Comment: Thanks @Carl this: `document.querySelectorAll(".bossLaser").forEach(function(c){
   c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
  });`worked for me.

Comment: Removing each child one by one will cause the browser to redraw and repaint on each child removed. if you have many spans a better solution would be to add the spans to a doc fragment, then to a parent container, and when ready to remove, remove the parent container removing all spans in one reflow.

Comment: Not always, modern browser wait for JavaScript execution to be finished, before repainting anything

Comment: @tech-e not on a document fragment darlin

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already specifying a class:

```
spanVar.className = "redCircle";
```

you can use that to select all those elements and remove them:

```
$('.redCircle').remove();
```